# laravel scopes with relation and conditions

Tags: php, laravel, scope

i have this laravel scope code

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $builder->whereDoesntHave('getPermissionData');
}
```

everything working fine till now what i need is to wright conditions 
like this

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    /*
        if($builder->whereHas('getPermissionData'))
        {
            check the relation 
            and do some code here
        }
    */
    $builder->whereDoesntHave('getPermissionData');
}
```

is that possible or not

Comment: Can you explain what your end goal is? There may be a better way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: i want to check if user has permission to see item or not and item relation in lots of places in the script so before get item i want to check if user has permission to see the item or not

Comment: i have permissions table like admin user editor ect ..and i have table called permission_items which has tow column permission_item_item_id and permission_item_permission_id and every auth user has one permission so i want to check if user has permission to see the item or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two different conditions in `or` with each others. You also should wrap this condition in a `where` clause so next conditions won't be in `or` aswell

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model) {
    $builder->where(function ($query) {
         $query->whereDoesntHave('getPermissionData')
               ->orWhereHas('getPermissionData', function ($permissionQuery) {
                   // Apply your condition to the relation query
               });
    });
}
```

Comment: can you check this link please https://i.postimg.cc/yNzqTygs/Capture.png

Comment: Just put `$permissionQuery->where('permission_id', $permission->id);`